# Css :checked showing containers that shold be hidden

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do simple Tabs on my page, so I have 3 tabs and 3 sections for them. Problem is that in first section i can see all sections containers, in second 2 last and in this last. And it should be simple one section for one tab.

What am i missing?

My html and code https://codepen.io/wojsza/pen/XWMOXXm :

```
.display__tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; }
  .display__tabs--tab {
    display: none; }
    .display__tabs--tab:checked ~ .display__tabs--label ~ .display__tabs--content {
      display: block; }
  .display__tabs--label {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 25px;
    color: #2e2e2e; }
    .display__tabs--label:hover {
      color: #aeaeae;
      background-color: #2e2e2e;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: underline; }
  .display__tabs--content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    order: 1;
    display: none; }
```

and html:

```
<div class="display__tabs">
    <input type="radio" class="display__tabs--tab" id="display-module-info" name="module" checked="checked" />
    <label class="display__tabs--label" for="display-module-info">Info</label>
    <div class="display__tabs--content">
      <p>Module</p>
    </div>

    <input type="radio" class="display__tabs--tab" id="display-module-wsu" name="module" />
    <label for="display-module-wsu" class="display__tabs--label">Wsu</label>
    <div class="display__tabs--content">
        <p>
            WSU
        </p>
    </div>

    <input type="radio" class="display__tabs--tab" id="display-module-sections" name="module" />
    <label for="display-module-sections" class="display__tabs--label">Sections</label>
    <div class="display__tabs--content">
        <p>
            SECTION
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly there! Just need to change the "~" into "+".

You wanna change your css on this part :

From

```css
.display__tabs--tab:checked ~ .display__tabs--label ~ .display__tabs--content {
      display: block; 
}
```

To

```css
.display__tabs--tab:checked + .display__tabs--label + .display__tabs--content {
      display: block; 
}
```

This caused by the css selector of ~ which select the general sibling, and you wanted to use +, because the radio element that being set to hidden and block, is adjacent sibling. Reference https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understanding-use-of-the-and-symbols-in-css-selectors-95552eb436f5

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a second class to `radio` inputs, and `display__tabs--content`. Then, you can just add CSS for each one of them.

```css
.display__tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.display__tabs--tab {
  display: none;
}

.tab1:checked ~ .display__tabs--label ~ .display__tabs--content.content1 {
  display: block;
}

.tab2:checked ~ .display__tabs--label ~ .display__tabs--content.content2 {
  display: block;
}

.tab3:checked ~ .display__tabs--label ~ .display__tabs--content.content3 {
  display: block;
}

.display__tabs--label {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 25px;
  color: #2e2e2e;
}
.display__tabs--label:hover {
  color: #aeaeae;
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.display__tabs--content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  order: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="display__tabs">
  <input type="radio" class="display__tabs--tab tab1" id="display-module-info" name="module" checked="checked" />
  <label class="display__tabs--label" for="display-module-info">Info</label>
  <div class="display__tabs--content content1">
    <p>Module</p>
  </div>

  <input type="radio" class="display__tabs--tab tab2" id="display-module-wsu" name="module" />
  <label for="display-module-wsu" class="display__tabs--label">Wsu</label>
  <div class="display__tabs--content content2">
    <p>
      WSU
    </p>
  </div>

  <input type="radio" class="display__tabs--tab tab3" id="display-module-sections" name="module" />
  <label for="display-module-sections" class="display__tabs--label">Sections</label>
  <div class="display__tabs--content content3">
    <p>
      SECTION
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```